# How to change background color of a selected column shiny R

Tags: css, colors, shiny, background

I have my shiny code here that aims to display the uploaded data as data table and makes you color the column that you're selecting in the selectinput. The code is logically working as the rendering texts works great but no color is detected!

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
 sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Upload your  CSV File'),
      htmlOutput("variables")
        ),
    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("TD"),
        tags$style(type="text/css",textOutput("T2"))

    ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
myData1 <- reactive({
  inFile <- input$file1
  if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
  data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,row.names=1)
  data
})
output$variables <- renderUI({
  req(myData1())
  df_init <- myData1() 
  for(i in c(1:ncol(df_init))){
    if((class(df_init[,i])=="integer") && length(unique(df_init[,i]))<=input$n){df_init[,i]<-factor(df_init[,i])}}
  x=sapply(df_init,class)
  x=(x=="numeric")
  df=df_init[,x]
  if (identical(df, '') || identical(df,data.frame())) return(NULL)
  selectInput(inputId = "V1", label = "Variables to use: Y", choices=names(df), selected=names(df[1]))
})
output$TD <- renderDataTable({
  data <- myData1()
  DT::datatable(data = data,options = list(pageLength = 10))
})
output$T2<-renderText({
  data<-myData1()
  if (is.null(data)) return()
  paste("#TD td:nth-child(",match(input$V1, colnames(data)),") {text-align:center;background-color:red;color: white;text-align:center}")  
})}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is a data sample

```
,Var,Lo,ES,Acidity,K232,K270,IP,OS,C 14:0,C 16:0,C 16:1,C 17:0,C 17:1,C 18:0,C 18:1,C 18:2,C 18:3,C 20:0,C 20:1,total,LLL,LnLO,LnLP,LLO,LnOO,PLL,LOO,LOP,PLP,OOO,POP,POO,AOL,SOO,SOP,Chlorophyll,b carotène,polyphenols ,Ethyl acetate,2- Methyl butanal,3- Methyl butanal,1-Penten-3-one,3-Hexanone,Hexanal,3-Pentanol,Trans-2-pentenal,1-Penten-3-ol,Cis-3-hexenal,Trans-2-hexenal,1-Pentanol,Hexyl acetate,Cis-3-hexenyl acetate,Cis-2-pentenol,6-Methyl-5-hepten-2-one,1-Hexanol,Trans-3-hexenol,Cis-3-hexenol,Trans-2-hexenol,Acetic acid,Butyric acid,H-   Tyr      ,Tyr ,DFOA,DFLA,Ac-Pin,Pin,EAA,OA,LA,total phenols (HPLC)
P1,chetoui,beja,sp,0.93,1.49,0.2,9.2,16.51,0.01,13.5,0.57,0.07,0.08,2.57,67.04,18.56,1.16,0.02,0.39,103.95,0.72,0.45,0.1,7.87,2.63,0.38,22.14,8.8,0.7,33.47,15.84,1.77,0.37,3.95,0.8,5.05,4.1,491.6,2.72,0.29,0.11,0.08,0.1,15.27,1.35,1.55,3.77,22.68,133.13,0.36,9.92,7.14,2.37,0.5,10.03,0.78,121.11,14.12,0.05,0.08,1.91,4.15,10.33,40.52,1.21,5.5,2.92,30.65,2.35,99.53
P2,chetoui,beja,sp,0.36,1.24,0.2,8.2,16.81,0.01,13.39,0.18,0.05,0.07,1.23,69.23,18.63,0.91,0.02,0.28,104,0.69,0.43,0.15,7.81,2.57,0.42,22.21,8.84,0.71,33.87,15.6,2.01,0.38,4.14,1.01,5.88,6.161,457.04,2.52,0.34,0.12,0.09,0.22,15.2,1.32,1.52,3.67,22.61,133.19,0.35,9.89,7.18,2.34,0.51,10.17,0.75,121.21,14.29,0.05,0.02,1.92,4.05,10.45,40.63,1.25,5.55,2.95,31.042,2.17,100.01
P3,chetoui,beja,sp,0.84,1.87,0.21,8.6,16.73,0.01,13.31,0.45,0.06,0.08,2.54,69.29,17.03,0.84,0.02,0.37,104,0.72,0.42,0.12,7.82,2.61,0.43,21.22,8.83,0.72,33.85,15.52,1.92,0.39,4.05,0.95,5.92,6.241,482.12,2.72,0.25,0.08,1.12,0.42,15.01,1.3,1.44,3.93,22.51,133.07,0.39,9.87,7.16,2.31,0.52,10.1,0.76,121.29,14.21,0.06,0.01,1.93,4.12,10.6,40.71,1.26,5.54,2.96,30.43,2.26,99.81
```

Comment: can you share a sample dataset you are using? I tried using my own CSV file but I think your code is not tailored for that.

Comment: I've added a data sample